# ng-option not selecting model value on first call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple drop downs with different data arrays. On Edit click, I want to set the selected value. I have set ng-model to be the object but its not working.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Category{{product.categoryDto}}</label> 
    <select ng-model="product.categoryDto" class="form-control" ng-options="a.categoryName for a in categories"></select>
</div>
```

Following is the edit code.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="editProduct(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
</button>
$scope.editProduct = function(row){
    console.log($scope.product.categoryDto);
    $scope.product = row;
    $scope.showAddProductForm = true;
    $scope.product.categoryDto = row.categoryDto;
};
```

In label categoryDto is showing correct values but not selecting the option. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: From what I can see on the ng-options you have objects as properties and in the ng-model you're trying to set specific property of that object. You should try to set the whole object as a model, not only categoryDto

Comment: working as expected - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/roVeov  , may be you are not passing row parameter during ng-click

Comment: categories is a list populated elsewhere and product.categoryDto is an object which is also displayed in label as shown in image. Row parameter is passed in click. See js code in snippet plz.

Comment: can you share click js as well , how parameter is passed and did you check codepen link?

Comment: updated the code and yes i checked but that is not the case. Check following link its working fine in plunker but not working in application http://plnkr.co/edit/B5TDQJ?p=preview

Comment: If i use object.id in ng-model then it works fine but that is to select an id not an object. I want to get an object 
<select
           ng-model="product.categoryDto.categoryId" class="form-control"
           ng-options="a.categoryId as a.categoryName for a in categories"></select>